# How to add id_user_created and id_user_edited to a Plans table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in rails and programming at all. I have to add a kind of id_user_created and id_user_edited in a table called Plan. These ids will help me to know which user created and edited a plan, but I have no idea how to do it. On my db schema, there is no relation between User and Plan but now that I have to add theses ids, I assume that I will have to create a relation, right? Thanks a lot.

**Models**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :plan
end
```

**Controller**

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @plan = Plan.new
  end
 
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @plan = Plan.new(plan_params)
    @plan.user = @user

    if @plan.save
      redirect_to plan_path(@plan), notice: 'O plano foi criado com sucesso.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    if @plan.update(plan_params)
      redirect_to @plan, notice: 'O plano foi editado com sucesso.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end


  private

  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:name, :duration, :price, :status, :default)
  end
  
end
```

**Route**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'pages#home'
  
  resources :plans do
    resources :accounts, only: %i[new create] do
    end
  end

  resources :payments, only: %i[index]
  resources :accounts, only: %i[index show edit update destroy] do
    resources :users, only: %i[new create] do
      resources :roles
    end
  end
  
  resources :users, only: %i[index show edit update destroy]
```

**Plans Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @plan] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Nome' %>
  <%= f.input :duration, label: 'Duração' %>
  <%= f.input :price, label: 'Preço' %>
  <%= f.input :status %>
  <%= f.input :default %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn-outline-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what are you see in ur db table. ? have you defined relationships between plans and users tables when you create them ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails you generate migrations to create foreign keys by using the `references` (aka `belongs_to`) type:

```
rails g migration add_user_to_plans user:references
```

Which generates the following migration:

```
class AddUserToPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :plans, :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

When you run the migration it creates a `plans.user_id` column which points to the users table.

If you want to call the column/association something else like `creator_id` you need to explicitly tell rails which table you are referencing. Just don't call your columns `id_user_created` unless you want to come off as a complete snowflake.

```
class AddCreatorToPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :plans, :creator, 
      null: false, 
      foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  end
end
```

And you also have to explicitly set up your association:

```
class Plan
  belongs_to :creator, 
   class_name: 'User',
   inverse_of: :plans
end

class User
  has_many :plans, 
    foreign_key: :creator_id,
    inverse_of: :plans
end
```

Your form is also off. When you're dealing with creating resources as the logged in user you don't want/need to nest the route.

```
<%= simple_form_for @plan do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Nome' %>
  <%= f.input :duration, label: 'Duração' %>
  <%= f.input :price, label: 'Preço' %>
  <%= f.input :status %>
  <%= f.input :default %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn-outline-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

And you can also trim that create method down by building the resource off the association on the current user:

```
def create
  @plan = current_user.plans.new(plan_params)
  if @plan.save
    redirect_to @plan, 
      notice: 'O plano foi criado com sucesso.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

While you could do the same thing and add an editor_id column to plans its probably not what you want as it will only let you record a single id and not something more useful like a history of who edited the record and when which requires a join table and this is really an entire question on its own.

Answer (score -1):

```
**Try add 's' to model in database relationship**



  class User < ApplicationRecord
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
      belongs_to :plans
    end

 <%= simple_form_for [@user, @user.plans] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :name, label: 'Nome' %>
      <%= f.input :duration, label: 'Duração' %>
      <%= f.input :price, label: 'Preço' %>
      <%= f.input :status %>
      <%= f.input :default %>
      <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn-outline-secondary" %>
    <% end %>
```